# CSS animation works through class but doesn't work through data-name for parent element

Tags: svg, css-animations

I am a graphic designer who wants to learn how to code :)
I need to find a way to call animations through **data-names**.
I found out that it works for a child but doesn't work for the parent element, but I can't find out why.
If I change **data-name** with a **class** it works perfectly, but due to the circumstances, I have to use only data-names.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

I know I can animate child-elements separately to have the same effect, but I think it is nice to find out what is the issue for the future.
Please check
Lines 5,6(style) and 41(g)

```html
<svg id="ed60e92c-8023-4b4e-a257-3580dabca02a" data-name="action_arrow2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 119.52 119.52"><defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84{fill:none;}.a6702ecc-977e-4ec2-8add-47217594510b{fill:yellow;}.fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313{fill:black;}
    
<!--  g [data-name="action_arrow2"] { Doesn't work -->
  .action_arrow2 {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: arrow2_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
@keyframes arrow2_animation {
      0% { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
      50% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%  { transform: rotate(-45deg); }}
  
  
  g [data-name="clockwise"] {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: clockwise_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
@keyframes clockwise_animation {
      0% { opacity: 1; }
      47% { opacity: 1; }
      50% { opacity: 0; }
      97% { opacity: 0; }
     100%  { opacity: 1; }}
  
  
   g [data-name="counterclockwise"] {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: counter_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
@keyframes counter_animation {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
      47% { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      97% { opacity: 1; }
     100%  { opacity: 0; } }
  </style>
  </defs>
  
  <g id="aeee668b-21ac-41e3-b248-485eb27a0a1b" data-name="action_arrow2" class="action_arrow2">
    <circle id="b4485f64-ea17-46a9-bfb3-7702974cac03" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
    
  <g id="a6f987a9-6dfa-4dd8-80b8-eecc39586c4c" data-name="circle_transparent">
  <path id="a0aa0306-a048-4ba8-8272-84096ecec18f" data-name="circle" class="a6702ecc-977e-4ec2-8add-47217594510b" d="M34.32,28.39a40.83,40.83,0,1,1-5.76,57.46A40.88,40.88,0,0,1,34.32,28.39ZM83.49,88.52a36.84,36.84,0,1,0-51.84-5.2A36.9,36.9,0,0,0,83.49,88.52Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
    
    
  <g id="a6bb816d-4d36-49e6-8262-1145b3d71b2a" data-name="clockwise">
        <circle id="eedbf415-6006-412e-a444-1528a8300e18" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
        <path id="e1f5490c-6a8d-44b8-8037-690f3b52b4d6" data-name="clockwise2" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M28.7,79.22A36.66,36.66,0,0,1,26.08,46l3.37,2,.15-12L19.16,41.88l3.46,2a40.66,40.66,0,0,0,2.66,37.38C26.2,82.81,29.52,80.57,28.7,79.22Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
        <path id="b89a253a-bf5f-41b1-853f-ff16fbdae36a" data-name="clockwise1" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M91.75,40.89a36.66,36.66,0,0,1,2.62,33.23l-3.37-2-.15,12,10.44-5.86-3.46-2a40.61,40.61,0,0,0-2.67-37.37C94.25,37.31,90.93,39.54,91.75,40.89Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
   </g>
    
   <g id="ad441e68-0db6-43d4-b7b7-ab1edf7c8b4d" data-name="counterclockwise">
        <circle id="ac342f71-48ac-449a-9aab-4699d3dd8ca4" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
        <path id="b9bdcf1a-9445-47b5-98dc-0c6920da0731" data-name="counterclockwise1" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M91.73,79.14A36.67,36.67,0,0,0,94.24,45.9l-3.36,2-.19-12,10.46,5.82L97.7,43.83a40.63,40.63,0,0,1-2.55,37.38C94.24,82.72,90.91,80.49,91.73,79.14Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
        <path id="a9e3bd80-2516-438c-8f1e-55b8e13567ad" data-name="counterclockwise2" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M28.55,41A36.67,36.67,0,0,0,26,74.25l3.37-2,.18,12L19.14,78.38l3.45-2.06a40.67,40.67,0,0,1,2.54-37.39C26.05,37.43,29.37,39.66,28.55,41Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
   </g>
</g> </g>
</svg>
```

Thank you,
Looking forward. It is my first post in the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the `g` element with `data-name="counterclockwise"`, use

`g[data-name="counterclockwise"] {`

instead of

`g [data-name="counterclockwise"] {`

(or leave out the `g` completely:)

`[data-name="counterclockwise"] {`

A space in css means a 'child selector': https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference.

```html
<svg id="ed60e92c-8023-4b4e-a257-3580dabca02a" data-name="action_arrow2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 119.52 119.52"><defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84{fill:none;}.a6702ecc-977e-4ec2-8add-47217594510b{fill:yellow;}.fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313{fill:black;}
    
g[data-name="action_arrow2"] {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: arrow2_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 }

    @keyframes arrow2_animation {
      0% { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
      50% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%  { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
    }
  
  
  g[data-name="clockwise"] {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: clockwise_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
@keyframes clockwise_animation {
      0% { opacity: 1; }
      47% { opacity: 1; }
      50% { opacity: 0; }
      97% { opacity: 0; }
     100%  { opacity: 1; }}
  
  
   g[data-name="counterclockwise"] {
      animation: 6s infinite;
      animation-name: counter_animation;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
@keyframes counter_animation {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
      47% { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      97% { opacity: 1; }
     100%  { opacity: 0; } }
  </style>
  </defs>
  
  <g id="aeee668b-21ac-41e3-b248-485eb27a0a1b" data-name="action_arrow2" class="action_arrow2">
    <circle id="b4485f64-ea17-46a9-bfb3-7702974cac03" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
    
  <g id="a6f987a9-6dfa-4dd8-80b8-eecc39586c4c" data-name="circle_transparent">
  <path id="a0aa0306-a048-4ba8-8272-84096ecec18f" data-name="circle" class="a6702ecc-977e-4ec2-8add-47217594510b" d="M34.32,28.39a40.83,40.83,0,1,1-5.76,57.46A40.88,40.88,0,0,1,34.32,28.39ZM83.49,88.52a36.84,36.84,0,1,0-51.84-5.2A36.9,36.9,0,0,0,83.49,88.52Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
    
    
  <g id="a6bb816d-4d36-49e6-8262-1145b3d71b2a" data-name="clockwise">
        <circle id="eedbf415-6006-412e-a444-1528a8300e18" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
        <path id="e1f5490c-6a8d-44b8-8037-690f3b52b4d6" data-name="clockwise2" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M28.7,79.22A36.66,36.66,0,0,1,26.08,46l3.37,2,.15-12L19.16,41.88l3.46,2a40.66,40.66,0,0,0,2.66,37.38C26.2,82.81,29.52,80.57,28.7,79.22Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
        <path id="b89a253a-bf5f-41b1-853f-ff16fbdae36a" data-name="clockwise1" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M91.75,40.89a36.66,36.66,0,0,1,2.62,33.23l-3.37-2-.15,12,10.44-5.86-3.46-2a40.61,40.61,0,0,0-2.67-37.37C94.25,37.31,90.93,39.54,91.75,40.89Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
   </g>
    
   <g id="ad441e68-0db6-43d4-b7b7-ab1edf7c8b4d" data-name="counterclockwise">
        <circle id="ac342f71-48ac-449a-9aab-4699d3dd8ca4" data-name="frame" class="bf17fc5c-7924-499b-959f-404e7a5d6c84" cx="59.76" cy="59.76" r="59.74"/>
        <path id="b9bdcf1a-9445-47b5-98dc-0c6920da0731" data-name="counterclockwise1" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M91.73,79.14A36.67,36.67,0,0,0,94.24,45.9l-3.36,2-.19-12,10.46,5.82L97.7,43.83a40.63,40.63,0,0,1-2.55,37.38C94.24,82.72,90.91,80.49,91.73,79.14Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
        <path id="a9e3bd80-2516-438c-8f1e-55b8e13567ad" data-name="counterclockwise2" class="fbbc3ad0-37ae-41ab-8c9e-860970eb1313" d="M28.55,41A36.67,36.67,0,0,0,26,74.25l3.37-2,.18,12L19.14,78.38l3.45-2.06a40.67,40.67,0,0,1,2.54-37.39C26.05,37.43,29.37,39.66,28.55,41Z" transform="translate(-0.41 -0.24)"/>
   </g>
</g> </g>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/spassvogel/pen/JjbmNxJ